Snowflake Time Travel is not working as expected after ALTER TABLE
I have a table in Snowflake. After I drop a column I try to use time travel, but the data is gone. Why?
How to reproduce:
create or replace table time_travel_test
as 
select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c
union all 
select 4,5,6;

select *
from time_travel_test;
-- A    B   C
-- 1    2   3
-- 4    5   6

set good_data_timestamp = current_timestamp();

alter table time_travel_test
drop column c;

select *
from time_travel_test
at(timestamp=>$good_data_timestamp);
-- A    B
-- 1    2
-- 4    5

Why is my data not there? How can I recover column C?

Don't worry - data is still there and time travel has done its job. You are not seeing the whole table when doing a select * at() only because select is using the current schema (not the past one) to parse the query.
To get the whole table back from the past you should clone it instead:
create table back_to_the_future_test
clone time_travel_test 
at(timestamp=>$good_data_timestamp);
;

select *
from back_to_the_future_test;
-- A    B   C
-- 1    2   3
-- 4    5   6


https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone#clone-objects-using-time-travel

